# Username/password for Oracle Linux 5.8 VirtualMachine

Tags: linux, virtualbox, oracle, rhel5

I have the Oracle Linux 5 ova (converted to VirtualBox).  The documentation I have seen mentions using either root/oracle or oracle/oracle to login. However that is not working.  Any references/documentation for this particular version of VM would be appreciated.

Following is documentation i have for oracle linux 6

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-admin/evaluating-linux-vb-1934676.html

[image]

Comment: If you're looking for documentation specifically to this VM, I'd start by looking where you got it from.  Including that info here may help someone assist you as well.

Comment: @yoonix OK. updated the question.

Comment: That documentation is for Oracle Linux 6, and your screenshot is Oracle Linux 5.  Isn't there any documentation where you downloaded the version you're asking about?

Comment: @yoonix.  I can not find any documentation precisely on version 5.X: this is the closest I could find.

Comment: That's not going to do you any good.  The passwords listed are specifically for that VM downloadable on that page.  There aren't default passwords that work on every version of Oracle Linux out there.  You don't need 'version 5.x' documentation, you need documentation from the exact place/person/organization you downloaded this one from. From the person or company that built it.  You may have better luck searching for how to change the root password.  Boot to single user, change password, reboot.

Comment: actually that's a useful suggestion.  I re-booted to single user mode and changed the passwords.